# Arrange List with Total

Tags: list-manipulation, summation

I created a list

```
t = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {2, 3, 4}]
```

whose result is

[image]

I would like to do a sum operation as follows

[image]

I used `Total` option, but I could not get it the way I wanted it.

Can you help me?

Comment: `Total[t, {3}]`

Comment: `Map[Total, t, {2}]`

Comment: btw, this literally one of the examples in the `Total` Tutorial, although it uses `Total[t, {-1}]` instead of `Total[t, {3}]`

Comment: Subscripts can unnecessarily complicate coding. Recommend indexed variables displayed as subscripted variables:  `Format[a[i__]] := Subscript[a, i];  t = Array[a, {2, 3, 4}]`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Map` with `Total` to the correct level.  To find the level you can use `TreeForm`:

```
TreeForm[t]
```

[image: Tree]

From this you can see the levels of the expressions.  You are trying to total the second level down (the third row in the diagram, as the top expression is at level 0), which makes the level spec in the map `Map[function, list, {2}]`.  Alternatively you can count upwards to the third level up - `Map[function, list, {-3}]`.

So to get the correct result:

```
Map[function, list, {-3}]
```

[image: Solution]